# When is it appropriate to request editing of a comment?

Tags: discussion

[Can editing comments as moderator trigger a notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74691/can-editing-comments-as-moderator-trigger-a-notification) implies that moderators have the ability to edit comments.

A certain user has a bad habit of spamming his web site in comments (and the link is irrelevant to the comment). However, one such comment by this user can't really be flagged as "not constructive" or "too chatty", as it *is* a valid comment aside from the link. I had raised a custom flag on it, but my custom description did not include a request to edit, it only requested a delete (I did not realize moderators could edit comments). It was understandably declined.

Would a custom flag along the lines of "Request edit of irrelevant web site link out of comment" have been acceptable? Is that the appropriate procedure for handling this type of comment? Is it actually appropriate to flag this type of comment for editing to begin with?

Comment: Note that this is *not* one of the two comments I mentioned in my other recent post here about reversing declined flags.

Comment: This is an example of comment-abuse, IMHO. Someone is taking advantage of the "2nd-class citizen" status of comments to excuse himself in some cheap salesmanship. Really annoying actually. That said, it seems easier to flag for deletion and notification to author of reasons thereof

Comment: Since comments are 2nd-class citizens, I wouldn't shy from outright deletion.

Comment: If this is about the comments I think it is (we don't see who flagged them, but what you're describing sound familiar), I declined those flags because the comments were not spam at all. The questions themselves were about the site he was working on, and the links were directly relevant to what he was talking about. In at least one place, he was asked by another person to show the site he was referring to, thus the link in the comment. I saw no self-promotion in any of this, nor any need to remove those.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks Brad; that could definitely be the case in *some* of his comments. In the *majority* I saw it was not the case, but that could have clouded my view of the valid minority. In any case, I'm not going to press the issue with reflags; I'll just file this all away for future reference.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for the link; that's an interesting proposal. As far as catching spam goes; on the rare occasion that I do see spammed links (whether in comments or posts) I usually head right over to data.se and look for others. That's actually how I came across all of the comments related to this particular instance (well, and `like '%derp%'`, `'%heh%'`, and `'%lol%'` turned up a couple suspects, too).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's *very* rare for moderators to edit someone else's comments.  We don't like to change someone's words when the comment is still attributed to the original author, with no revision showing that it was edited. Having said that, the situation you describe sounds like one of those few cases where an edit would be appropriate. A custom flag should be acceptable. A moderator can decide to either edit out the irrelevant link, or just delete the comment.

Comment: I do this occasionally, but usually to correct, say, an obvious typo.

Comment: Non-moderators can edit other people's comments?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Aaron is a moderator on dba.

Comment: Oh. Well, I do what Aaron does; fix the occasional obvious grammatical error.  I've partially removed rudeness in an otherwise constructive comment, but that is *extremely* rare (I could probably count the instances on one hand).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, fixing obvious typos is probably the only case I can think of when it's ok to change a comment. (Otherwise, I'm with Robert. It's extremely rare for me to remove part of someone's comment without just deleting the whole thing.)